# How to reduce the response time of external page loading in phonegap application?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I have developed a  application for android using phonegap. I am loading external HTML pages using  XMLHttpRequest . It is working fine but it takes time when i loading the external pages. How can i reduce the page loading time ?
My code as follows :

```
function loadHtmlPage(url){ //url - holds the name of the HTML page
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();     
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4){           
        document.getElementById("externalpagecont").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;   
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url , true);
    xmlhttp.send(null); 
}
```

Comment: Update your networking cables, your networking equipment, your ISP?

Comment: It is a  offline mobile application.

Comment: So the "external" pages refer to locally stored web pages?

Comment: yes all HTML pages are local web  pages

Comment: You say your are loading "external" HTML pages but below you say that the app is an offline application and you are talking about locally stored web pages. 

If they are already on the local device, I don't think you could make it any faster unless they are somehow already stored in memory?

Comment: Pre-Caching (some of) your external pages could improve response time. Using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#localStorage) for this is a good starting point.

Comment: @alex23: phonegap applications are normally based on html5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the comments, you are using an offine mobile application, and the *`external`* pages are actually local pages bundled with the app.  So network latency is not your issue.

If this is not the case, try including the pages in your www folder.

Assuming you have done that, one idea is to make your app be a single page and manipulate accordingly.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
...
    <div id="page1">....</div>
    <div id="page2">....</div>
...
</html>
```

Then in javascript

```
function loadHtml(id) { /* hide / show / get content / your business needs here */}
```